# Problem with VS08 performance combined with virus-scanner

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Hey,
At the moment, I have big problems with my VS08 IDE performance. 
When I scroll my text-document, it lags.
Can somebody who made experience with this problem tell me, if this lags have to do with my Microsoft Forefront Virus-Scanner ?

Comment: I would think the lag is more likely caused by either a low-end video card or limited RAM.

Comment: 8GB DDR2, 2.8 Core 2 Duo, SSD. No :-(

Comment: All that RAM has little use for a 32-bit process.  Create a new solution with just a simple project.  Does it lag?  Then look for an external cause.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that scrolling a text document is affected by a Virus Scanner.  The documents in Visual Studio are fully loaded into memory and hence after the initial load, won't be affected by file system items like the Virus Scanner.

It's far more likely the cause is a 3rd party plugin, an extremely large file or solution.  Can you give us a bit more detail on exactly what is running inside Visual Studio and how big of a solution you have open?

Comment: Hey, 1900 Files in solution, 5000 rows. My CodeRush PlugIn is deinstalled.

Comment: @Patrik, try opening that file in a branch new solution and see if the problem repros